# CSS float: Why doesn't the second box shift to the left side of my floated box

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML & CSS. I would like to know why the second box does not float to the side of the first box. As I understand if a box of specific width is floated, then other divs will float to the left of the floated box/div until there is no more space to accommodate on the same line box.

```css
   #content-wrapper {
     border: 1px solid blue;
     width: 100%
   }
   .first-box {
     width: 450px;
     border: 1px solid red;
     float: left;
   }
   .first-box h2 {
     background: url(img/top-menu-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
     line-height: 45px;
     padding-left: 15px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
   }
   .second-box {
     width: 5%;
     border: 1px solid red;
   }
   </style>
```

```html
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div class="first-box">
    <h2>Welcome to My Engg.</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="second-box">
    <p>Some Side bar text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: check your math.  Inspect the elements in the console by hovering over them to see their box model.

Comment: Please don't use float for this! This would be more effective using display and/or positioning instead.

Comment: did you forget float-left on second box?

Comment: @jbutler483 can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: @lharby: Since floating elements bring the element out of the doucment flow, it means you need to add clear fixes/etc to 'add them back in'. Since Positioning and/or display (more likely display IMO), you *avoid* doing this, it means your elements are how you want them, and also leaves 'space' in your document for it. (have you ever noticed that when you float elements, stuff appears behind it?). That's due to the floating elements.

Comment: @lharby its because the float style ignores the regular html layout system.  as you can see in the demo by OP, the start spot is top left so without the float, it would be first div followed by the second div next to it on the right. when you float the first div, it "floats" apart from layout system, thus the second div doesnt see the first div, so it goes to the top left of the html layout.  however, when it gets there, it sees that theres something there, so it just elongates its height until it can place its content

Comment: @jbutler483 Well I love clearfix. For my own approach I prefer to use floats (especially thinking of responsive design) rather than take a div which is naturally a block element and change it's display type.

Comment: @lharby: I actually said this earlier today: *don't fix what's not broken*. You may like it, but given more experience/time you'll decide to leave it behind, since it causes more issues than it's worth. Anyway, *changing its display settings* is just like changing its 'background color', for example. It's *made to be customised*. Whereas floating items its *physically* removing it from the DOM tree (that's not easy to work with) compared to display/positioning. There's not a time where you can't do positioning/display and *have* to use floating elements (that i've come across, anyway)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set display:inline-block

**CSS**

```
#content-wrapper{
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.first-box {
  width:450px;
  border:1px solid red;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}

.first-box h2{
  background:url(img/top-menu-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  line-height:45px; 
  padding-left:15px; 
  margin-bottom:15px;
  display:inline-block;
 }

.second-box{
  width:5%;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block; //HERE YOUR FIX
 }
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tz04kf0g/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a float left to any other item you wish to float:

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/bjgpsm1n/

I've just added:

```
 .second-box{float:left /* other css */}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of going about fixing this.

The simplest way would be for you to simply add `float: left` to the class `.second-box`

Codepen link of working example: [LINK TO EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbmEvv)

Floats will sometimes cause you probelms with things like this.

Have you thought of using `display: inline-block`?